# problem when create project with zend framwork using wamp server

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

**strong text**
I'm using wamp version : 2.4 php version 7.1
I have problem like this when I try to create project in my www of wamp
please help advice . Thank you so much
[image]

Composer  :

{
"name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
"description": "Skeleton Application for Zend Framework zend-mvc applications",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"keywords": [
"framework",
"mvc",
"zf"
],
"homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
"require": {
"php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
"zendframework/zend-component-installer": "^1.0 || ^2.1",
"zendframework/zend-skeleton-installer": "^0.1.7 || ^1.0",
"zendframework/zend-mvc": "^3.1.1",
"zfcampus/zf-development-mode": "^3.2"
},
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
"Application\": "module/Application/src/"
}
},
"autoload-dev": {
"psr-4": {
"ApplicationTest\": "module/Application/test/"
}
},
"extra": {
"zend-skeleton-installer": [
{
"name": "zendframework/zend-developer-tools",
"constraint": "^1.2.3",
"prompt": "Would you like to install the developer toolbar?",
"module": true,
"dev": true
},
{
"name": "zendframework/zend-cache",
"constraint": "^2.9.0",
"prompt": "Would you like to install caching support?",
"module": true
},
{
"name": "zendframework/zend-db",
"constraint": "^2.10.0",
"prompt": "Would you like to install database support (installs zend-db)?",
"module": true
},
{
"name": "zendframework/zend-mvc-form",
"constraint": "^1.0",
"prompt": "Would you like to install forms support?",
"module": true
},
{
"name": "zendframework/zend-json",
"constraint": "^3.1.2",
"prompt": "Would you like to install JSON de/serialization support?"
},
{
"name": "zendframework/zend-log",
"constraint": "^2.11",
"prompt": "Would you like to install logging support?",
"module": true
},
{
"name": "zendframework/zend-mvc-console",
"constraint": "^1.2.0",
"prompt": "Would you like to install MVC-based console support? (We recommend migrating to zf-console, symfony/console, or Aura.CLI)",
"module": true
},
{
"name": "zendframework/zend-mvc-i18n",
"constraint": "^1.1.1",
"prompt": "Would you like to install i18n support?",
"module": true
},
{
"name": "zendframework/zend-mvc-plugins",
"constraint": "^1.0.1",
"prompt": "Would you like to install the official MVC plugins, including PRG support, identity, and flash messages?",
"module": true
},
{
"name": "zendframework/zend-psr7bridge",
"constraint": "^1.2.0",
"prompt": "Would you like to use the PSR-7 middleware dispatcher?"
},
{
"name": "zendframework/zend-session",
"constraint": "^2.9.1",
"prompt": "Would you like to install sessions support?",
"module": true
},
{
"name": "phpunit/phpunit",
"constraint": "^5.7.27 || ^6.5.14 || ^7.5.17",
"prompt": "Would you like to install testing support?",
"dev": true
},
{
"name": "zendframework/zend-test",
"constraint": "^3.3.0",
"prompt": "Would you like to install MVC testing tools for testing support?",
"dev": true
},
{
"name": "zendframework/zend-servicemanager-di",
"constraint": "^1.2.1",
"prompt": "Would you like to install the zend-di integration for zend-servicemanager?",
"module": true
}
]
},
"scripts": {
"cs-check": "phpcs",
"cs-fix": "phpcbf",
"development-disable": "zf-development-mode disable",
"development-enable": "zf-development-mode enable",
"development-status": "zf-development-mode status",
"post-create-project-cmd": [
"@development-enable",
"php bin/update-gitignore.php"
],
"serve": "php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public",
"test": "phpunit"
}
}

Comment: Could you post your `composer.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install composer version 1:

```
cd project_dir
wget https://getcomposer.org/composer-1.phar
```

And then:

```
php composer-1.phar install
```